# file_get_html() doesnt show content for logged user

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have proble with Simple HTML DOM parser for php. I want to check DOM for logged user, but file_get_html() returns page which shows when nobody is logged in. I am using Magento CMS.

There is any workaround for this?

Comment: **file_get_html** don't send cookies with the request, that's why it returns the page which shows when nobody is logged in

Comment: You should look into using curl. That will let you send cookie data.

Comment: As Jeremy said, use curl to login and retrieve html data, then load it as dom using `str_get_html()`... you can find a lot of examples here on SO how to login with curl...